# Can I attach a metal box for a vanity light to a wood cross?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, code-compliance

I am redoing a new bathroom.  I have a metal electrical box that I want to replace (because it is an odd size from the 50s).  The current one is simply screwed to a wood cross (2x4) running horizontally.  Can I screw the new one into wood?  I know I can but is it code compliant?

Comment: It's unclear if you're trying to connect a metal box or a vanity light (or both), what this "wooden cross" is, or why using a "metal rod" would be the normal way to connect ... whatever it is you're trying to connect. If you can link to examples of the products you're talking about and/or take pictures of what you have we can provide much better help.

Comment: @gregmac - is that better?

Comment: @Tom:  that is an improvement, but what is the wood cross?  Is it part of the framing?

Comment: @wallyk - yea it is part of the framing - just a 2x4 used to hold up the old metal box.

Comment: A picture might make it clearer.